Does enabling FILESTREAM for file I/O access improve performance and manageability in handling file data?
I am trying my best to craft my question as straightforward and clear as possible. So I will start by quoting this answer thread saying that,

If you want to read and write FILESTREAM data from Windows, click
Enable FILESTREAM for file I/O streaming access.

On my machine, I have successfully set up FILESTREAM with SQL SERVER and already processed data from its table to API, but I am wondering what "Enable FILESTREAM for file I/O streaming access" can do in terms of performance optimization.
Given these settings:

The main question here is, does this introduce different access and data retrieval between the request point and file location?
What I mean is, if I can manage the FILESTREAM data in SQL Server without these mentioned settings, does this configuration offer the same control over the data that will be responsible for accessing when there is a request for the corresponding file data?
I haven't seen yet if it is useful or not, but I think that it has potential usefulness in my use case... However, my main goal here is to optimize performance without sacrificing granular control and manageability between the file data and application destination (API or something).


What I mean is, if I can manage the FILESTREAM data in SQL Server without these mentioned settings, does this configuration offer the same control over the data that will be responsible for accessing when there is a request for the corresponding file data?

No, these settings are specifically to allow access to filestream data utilizing Windows APIs and client applications to directly deal with the data. It allows for a different access path, for example, for an application that might need to add in large files which are generated (such as a video file) but that doesn't directly interact with SQL Server.

I haven't seen yet if it is useful or not, but I think that it has potential usefulness in my use case... However, my main goal here is to optimize performance without sacrificing granular control and manageability between the file data and application destination (API or something)

Unless you're writing your own client application to access filestream data directly for use in other Windows APIs, then this does absolutely nothing. It doesn't change the access paths of SQL Server, it doesn't speed anything up, it doesn't change how the database engine works.

Very well said. Thanks for your time in answering my question. Things are clarified now. But then I found out that the configuration and implementation is more complex than I thought.
